# Hide and Close is not working in all my form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a label with a text "X" and I use this to close my forms. I have this code in my login:

```
private void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (userLevel.IndexOf("ADMIN") + 1 > 0)
    {
        Save_Data();
        using (AdminGateOpt adminOptions = new AdminGateOpt())
       {
         adminOptions.gUsers = User;
         adminOptions.windowNumber = windowNumber;
         adminOptions.userDetails = userLevel.Split('|');
         adminOptions.ShowDialog();
         Close();
       }
    }
}
```

..and if the `userlevel` is an admin, then it will go to another form:

```
private void btnInGate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to go in In-Gate Form?", String.Empty, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        ReadBarCodeInGate gateForm = new ReadBarCodeInGate();
        gateForm.gUsers = gUsers;
        gateForm.windowNumber = windowNumber;
        gateForm.userDetails = userDetails;
        gateForm.ShowDialog();
        Hide();
    }        
}


private void buttonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    login Login = new login();
    Login.ShowDialog();
    Hide();
}
```

And it's also the same to other forms that suddenly it became like this, that once I hit the X label button it will go to another form but it wont close nor hide the previous form/s.

Comment: `gateForm.ShowDialog();` stops next line from executing until dialog is closed

Comment: T.S. thanks my stupid application is working now, but care to explain why it became like that? because yesterday it was like that also, and it's perfectly fine.

Comment: when you do "ShowDialog", nothing below this line executes until your dialog is closed. That is the idea behind - wait for end of execution.

Comment: I think Show() won't stop execution, will it?

Comment: @AccessDenied no